# JPA CriteriaQuery projection with lists

Tags: java, collections, jpa-2.0, projection, criteria-api

I'm trying to make a query using a wrapper class as result type. Sorry for the long post but I want to make my question as complete as possible.
The root class has 3 lists that I want to retrieve:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cash")
public final class Cash extends BaseSimpleModel {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id", sequenceName = "cash_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "id")
    private Long cashID;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cashID")
    private List<CashAllowedValue> allowedValueList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cashID")
    private List<CashAllowedCurrency> allowedCurrencyList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cashID")
    private List<CashAllowedCashier> allowedCashierList;
    ... getters and setters
}
```

Here is my wrapper class:

```
public class CashQueryResult extends QueryResult {
    private Long cashID;
    private String description;
    private List<CashAllowedValue> allowedValueList;
    private List<CashAllowedCurrency> allowedCurrencyList;
    private List<CashAllowedCashier> allowedCashierList;

    public CashQueryResult(Long id, String description, List<CashAllowedValue> allowedValueList, List<CashAllowedCurrency> allowedCurrencyList, List<CashAllowedCashier> allowedCashierList)
    {
        this.cashID = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.allowedValueList = allowedValueList;
        this.allowedCurrencyList = allowedCurrencyList;
        this.allowedCashierList = allowedCashierList;
    }
    ... getters
}
```

And here is my query:

```
public final List<CashQueryResult> getQRList(final CashQueryParameter cashQP, final QueryHint queryHint) {
    List<CashQueryResult> cashQRL = null;
    try {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final PredicateBuilder pb = new PredicateBuilder(cb);
        final CriteriaQuery<CashQueryResult> cq = cb.createQuery(CashQueryResult.class);
        final Root<Cash> cash = cq.from(getModelClass());

        // Joins.
        final ListJoin<Cash, CashAllowedValue> allowedValueList = cash.join(Cash_.allowedValueList, JoinType.LEFT);
        final ListJoin<Cash, CashAllowedCurrency> allowedCurrencyList = cash.join(Cash_.allowedCurrencyList, JoinType.LEFT);
        final ListJoin<Cash, CashAllowedCashier> allowedCashierList = cash.join(Cash_.allowedCashierList, JoinType.LEFT);

        // Paths.
        final Path<ValueTypeEnum> valueType = allowedValueList.get(CashAllowedValue_.valueType);
        final Path<Currency> currency = allowedCurrencyList.get(CashAllowedCurrency_.currency);
        final Path<IntranetUser> intranetUser = allowedCashierList.get(CashAllowedCashier_.cashier);

        // Expressions. Just for testing purposes.
        final Expression<List<CashAllowedValue>> cashAllowedValueListExpression = cash.get(Cash_.allowedValueList);
        final Expression<List<CashAllowedCurrency>> cashAllowedCurrencyExpression = cash.get(Cash_.allowedCurrencyList);
        final Expression<List<CashAllowedCashier>> cashAllowedCashierExpression = cash.get(Cash_.allowedCashierList);

        cq.distinct(true);
        cq.select(cb.construct(CashQueryResult.class, cash.get(Cash_.cashID), cash.get(Cash_.description),
            // cash.get(Cash_.allowedValueList), cash.get(Cash_.allowedCurrencyList), cash.get(Cash_.allowedCashierList) // does not work
            // cashAllowedValueListExpression, cashAllowedCurrencyExpression, cashAllowedCashierExpression // does not work
            allowedValueList, allowedCurrencyList, allowedCashierList // does not work
        ));

        // cq.multiselect(cash.get(Cash_.cashID), cash.get(Cash_.description),
        //     allowedValueList, allowedCurrencyList, allowedCashierList
        // ); // does not work

        cq.where(cb.and(pb.like(cash.get(Cash_.description), cashQP.getDescription()), pb.equal(valueType, cashQP.getValueType()), pb.equal(currency.get(Currency_.currencyID), cashQP.getCurrencyID()), pb.equal(intranetUser.get(IntranetUser_.agentID), cashQP.getIntranetUserID())));
        cq.orderBy(cb.asc(cash.get(Cash_.description)));

        final TypedQuery<CashQueryResult> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
        tq.setFirstResult(queryHint.getFirstResult());
        tq.setMaxResults(queryHint.getMaxResults());
        cashQRL = tq.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new EJBException(t.getMessage());
    }
    return cashQRL;
}
```

Finally, the exception (it varies depending on what select method I try but it's always something like this):

```
2011-09-12 16:12:26,165 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.ebizlink.adonis.erp.model.support.CashQueryResult] [cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.ebizlink.adonis.erp.model.support.CashQueryResult]
2011-09-12 16:12:26,169 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-2) javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.ebizlink.adonis.erp.model.support.CashQueryResult]
[select distinct new com.ebizlink.adonis.erp.model.support.CashQueryResult(generatedAlias0.cashID, generatedAlias0.description, generatedAlias1, generatedAlias2, generatedAlias3)
 from com.ebizlink.adonis.erp.model.Cash as generatedAlias0
    left join generatedAlias0.allowedValueList as generatedAlias1
    left join generatedAlias0.allowedCurrencyList as generatedAlias2
    left join generatedAlias0.allowedCashierList as generatedAlias3
 where ( 1=1 ) and ( 1=1 ) and ( 1=1 ) and ( 1=1 )
 order by generatedAlias0.description asc]
```

For reference, here is the [PredicateBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/pandora2/source/browse/products/pandora2/trunk/src/main/java/com/ebizlink/pandora2/server/ejb/util/PredicateBuilder.java) just in case.
I searched the web but I couldn't find somebody that is trying to retrieve many lists.
Am I missing something obvious? Multiple fetches are a no go (hibernate bug), and I can't make the lists Eager either.

Another related question would be:
Can I make a query so, that the lists of my wrapper class are also entity wrappers and not entities? (For example: Instead of using Cashiers, just get first name and last name, and use a list of CashierWrapper which holds both strings)

I really thank you and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you cannot do that, what specification says about arguments to constructor expression:

> constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {,constructor_item}* ) 
>   constructor_item ::=
>    single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable

And lists (collection_valued_field) you try to offer to constructor is not any of the constructor_item.

Comment: It's true. Thanks! I'll see what I can do then.